# Asymptote: Sending a parameter to function in contour

Tags: asymptote

I want to produce an animation of a graph with Asymptote. To achieve this the function needs a parameter `d`;

```
real f(real x, real y) {
    
    return (x^2 + y^2 + d * x);
    }

guide[][] thegraphs = contour(f, a=(-2,-2), b=(2,2), new real[] {0});
```

How we can send a parameter using the contour?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578982/234326

Comment: @justonly thanks for the link, interesting allowed solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Asymptote there are so-called anonymous functions (see [here](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Ebowman/publications/asyTUG.pdf), page 290) can be created with the keyword `new`, so that function definition in your example could be simplified without using programming tricks (you are difficult ^^ your trick is quite comfortable!).

[image]

```
size(5cm);
import graph;
import contour;

typedef real function(real, real);
function f(real d) {
return new real(real x, real y) {
return x^2 + y^2 -1+ d*x^2*y^2;
};
}

pen[] c={red, blue,purple,orange}; c.cyclic=true; // for different Edwards curves

for(int d=100; d > 0; d -= 10) {
guide[][] thegraphs = contour(f(d), a=(-2,-2), b=(2,2), new real[] {0},nx=200,operator..);
// nx=200 >>> for larger sample (default nx=100,ny=nx)
// operator.. >>> smoother join
draw(thegraphs[0],c[d]);
}

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

I hope you can adapt this to your animation. By the way, I am very impressive with recently-discovered Edwards curves and their application in cryptography.

Asymptote is rich in mathematical flavor!

**Update** Animation version

[image]

```
// x.asy >>> x.pdf >>> making GIF ưith ImageMagick command in the command line window
// magick -density 200 x.pdf -alpha remove x.gif
unitsize(2cm);
import contour;
import animate;

typedef real function(real, real);
function f(real d) {
return new real(real x, real y) {
return x^2 + y^2 -1+ d*x^2*y^2;
};
}
real a=1.25;
draw(box((a,a),(-a,-a)),invisible); 
draw((a,0)--(-a,0)^^(0,a)--(0,-a),gray); 
animation A;

for(real d=360; d > -1; d -= 5) {
save();
guide[][] Edwards = contour(f(d), a=(-1,-1), b=(1,1), new real[] {0},nx=200,operator..);
draw(Edwards[0],blue);
label("$d = $ "+string(d),(-a+.2, -a+.2),align=E);
A.add();
restore();
}
erase();
A.movie();
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely I will try. I wonder which one is faster ( I will test the speed). I couldn't solve the flickering text for d values. Any explanation? Is this a part of a book?

Comment: @kelalaka What is the flickering text? I don't get it. If you describe in more details, I will try helping when I am free. The speed seems not so fast when increasing smoothness.

Comment: I've put the current d value of the curve on the bottom left, if you wait around the twenties you will see that the position changes. Is is just `label(format("d = %4.1f",i),(-1.25, -1.25),align=E);`

Comment: @kelalaka an usual trick: please try `draw(box((2,2),(-2,-2)),invisible); ` to make  bounding box fixed, so the animation will be fine!

Comment: @kelalaka something like this? `size(5cm);
import graph;
import contour;

typedef real function(real, real);
function f(real d) {
return new real(real x, real y) {
return x^2 + y^2 -1+ d*x^2*y^2;
};
}

pen[] c={red, blue,purple,orange}; c.cyclic=true; // for different Edwards curves

draw(box((-1.5,1.5),(1.5,-1.75)),gray); 

for(int d=10; d > 0; d -= 10) {
guide[][] thegraphs = contour(f(d), a=(-2,-2), b=(2,2), new real[] {0});
draw(thegraphs[0],c[d]);
label(format("d = ",d),(0, -1.25),align=(0,0));
}

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
`

Comment: I see. The following points were a mess without format, I've used this to solve them `string( floor(i * 10 )/10)`. Does the posted image is produced exactly with this code? I've smaller and nonsmooth drawings.

Comment: @kelalaka yes! I use `magick -density 200 Edwards.pdf -alpha remove Edwards.gif` for gif

Comment: Ok, it turns out [Ubuntu uses ImageMagick version 6, not 7](https://askubuntu.com/q/1315603/480954), I need the `convert` command. One more issue to reproduce the same result; I compile with `asy x.as` and that produce gif for animations by default. Forcing output the pdf is a mess. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my issue with programming tricks as;

```
real g(real x, real y, real d) {
    
    return (x^2 + y^2 + d * x);
}

animation A=animation(global=false);
for(int i=300; i != 1; i -= 1) {

    erase();

    real f(real x, real y) {
        
        return g(x, y, i);
    }

    guide[][] thegraphs = contour(f, a=(-2,-2), b=(2,2), new real[] {0});

    draw(thegraphs[0]);

    A.add(BBox(1cm, nullpen));
}
erase();
A.movie(delay=240);
```

Here is the animation for Edwards curves;

[image]

Comment: I'm open to any other ideas.